# What is a branch number in the PAEQ algorithm?

Tags: aes, authenticated-encryption, terminology

I'm reading an article about authenticated encryption algorithm - PAEQ.

It uses a permutation function AESQ, which has transormations from AES. And there is written about MegaSBoxes, which contain 4 rounds of AES transformation. So, there are 1 active MegaSBox in 4 rounds and 5 active MegaSBox in 8 rounds (because of branch number - 5).

So, the question is what is a branch number and why there are 5 MegaSBoxes, not 2?

More info in [this paper](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round1/paeqv1.pdf) (section 3.2.3, after lemma 3).

Comment: Please add a citation or link to the article you are reading for context.

Comment: @asukaev: A paper in which branch number is involved is: www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/982865.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In AES, the MixColumns transform as a branch number of 5, this is because a change to a single byte input causes 4 of the output bytes to change. Like branches of a tree, 1+4=5. This is because MixColumns uses an MDS matrix for multiplications against the input.

AESQ operates on entire 128-bit blocks, which are further broken down into AES round operations. 2 AES round operations create full diffusion of the 128-bit block, so a single AESQ round consists of 2 AES rounds, in 4 parallel paths, followed by a shuffle operation so that 4 bytes from every AES round group go to a different group for the next round. What I am callling an AESQ round here is the output of a shuffle to the next shuffled output, I believe they call this 2 rounds in the paper.

Because the 2 AES rounds offer full diffusion, the branching of AESQ is a change 1 AES input block resulting in a change to 4 bytes of each AES output block. I color coded the blocks to show the distribution of modified bytes due to a change in any input byte over a single AESQ round (built from 8 AES rounds).

[image]

Therefore, just like in AES, we need 2 AESQ rounds for full diffusion of a single bit change to the the 512-input. This involves 16 AES rounds and 2 shuffle operations. This is considered MegaMixColumns plus MegaSubBytes, with a branch number of 5. This is called 4 rounds in the paper.

Comment: and why there are 5 MegaSBoxes in 8 rounds? In 4 rounds - 1. So, there might be 2 MegaSBoxes in 8?