# What is the meaning of weight in cryptography and how is it related to branch number?

Tags: aes

I am trying to understand the mixcolumn design of AES. I read that the branch number is 5 and there was a definition that referred to weight of vectors. What is weight of a vector?

Answer (score 2):

In cryptography, *"weight*" of a vector of bits is most often the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), that is the number of non-zero bits in the vector. But in this AES context, that's most probably the "*bundle weight*" of a vector of bundles of bits (e.g. a vector of bytes), defined as the number of non-zero bundles.

In the AES context, the *"(differential) (bundle) branch number"* of a Boolean transformation with respect to a bundle partition, as defined by Joan Daemen and Vincent Rijmen in [*The Design of Rijndael* (2002)](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540425809), section 9.3, is a measure of [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion). It is defined as the minimum bundle weight of the XOR of two distinct input/output combinations of said transformation. For MixColumns, that's the minimum number of bytes that can change between two distinct input/output combinations (of a total of 32 bytes), or equivalently the minimum number of bytes in a non-zero input/output combination; which is 5.

This is consistent with the general definition of Hamming weight in coding theory, where, for a given symbol alphabet, the weight of a nonzero symbol is $1$ while the weight of the zero symbol is $0.$ The designers of AES used MDS codes over the finite field $GF(2^8)$ (which can be represented by binary vectors of length 8, i.e., the vector space $GF(2)^8$). This is a $[length=8,dimension=4,min.~distance=5]$ code and the minimum weight (same as minimum distance since the code is linear) is $5$. This minimum weight corresponds to the guarantee that there are at least 5 total nonzero bytes amongst the 4 input and 4 output bytes (the number of input bytes is the dimension of the code and the number of input+output bytes is the length) of the $\textsf{MixCols}$ mapping.

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33174/555) further discusses the branch number.

Thanks for the many useful contributions in comments!

Comment: I have seen branch number consistently defined as $B(\theta) = min(w_t(a) + w_t(\theta(a)))$ for nonzero 0 in the works of [Joan Daemen and company](http://jda.noekeon.org/JDA_LKN_VRI_LinFram_2001.pdf)

Comment: The weight for AES, e.g., is based on symbol weight where symbols are in $GF(2)^8,$ and any nonzero Vector in $GF(2)^8$ (any nonzero Byte if you like) has weight 1. This is because the MDS code used in mixing has the same alphabet.

Comment: @fgrieu you are right that the term is overloaded and carelessly used.

Comment: Note that the Hamming weight is defined as the number of nonzero symbols, which don't have to be bits. So Hamming weight also applies to $\mathbb{F}_2^8$ and the comment by @kodlu doesn't contradict with the term "Hamming weight".

Comment: In the second paragraph, it is written "of a total of 32 bytes". Is this mean that two round have separately 32(16+16) "bundle", and at max 32 of then can be active(when at least one byte from each column is active initially)? @Aleph